# Using '>>' across gcc and visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

We are writing an application that compiles with both gcc and Visual C++. Some team members only use Visual C++/Windows, and others only use gcc/linux. Due to differences between compilers the build sometimes breaks. I have "fixed" several scenarios that lead to build breaks using compiler options to enable/disable warnings, but currently I am stuck with the ">>" used within C++ templates.

Visual Studio seems to have unilaterally extended the standard to include ">>" as a valid expression within templates (this is valid only in the proposed C++0x). But gcc does not accept this as a valid template. Now I am unable to find an option in Visual Studio to disallow ">>" or in gcc to allow ">>". How should I proceed?

Note: This question is about the double angle bracket, not the right shift operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC currently ([since version 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)) supports this via:

```
g++ --std=c++0x -o output file1.cpp file2.cpp ...
```

You have to explicitly specify that your source code is written in C++0x standard.

Comment: The problem with this is that C++0x is experimental i.e. some features may be removed as the standard evolves. But probably this would be the approach I have to take.

Comment: @Amit Kumar: yes it is experimental but the `Right angle brackets` feature will exist forever.

Comment: But `> >` will also continue to work forever, and has the additional advantage that it also works _now_. The problem with enabling C++0x extensions for GCC might be that this will make the GCC users introduce code that VC can't deal with. Sorry, but I don't like this suggestion. When you're doing cross platform stuff, you need to settle for what's available _and stable_ on all the platforms. C++1x isn't.

Comment: @Amit: Features won't be removed from it. It is feature complete, and the *only* changes they're doing from now on are minor bugfixes and changes in wording.

Answer (score 9):

I would separate them to > >. That is what the current standards require; it is the most correct and portable code. As far as I'm aware, gcc won't even compile if the angle brackets are next to each other.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that the team members using Visual Studio do not mind using ">>". This causes a build break.

Comment: Then you need to enforce a coding standard. sbi's suggestion sounds good. All coders need to write code that works for everyone. If they're breaking the build, they're doing it wrong!

Comment: Visual Studio also allows not writting `typename` to refer to a type that is dependent within another template. What are you going to do there? The problem is simple, and the solution is also simple. Use standard C++ and not compiler extensions if you want portability. That or decide for a single compiler (Comeau will fit there) that is also really standard compliant.

Comment: You may suggest the VS developers to periodically compile their code also with MinGW and fix the errors that come up.

Comment: @David, @Matteo What you say makes sense. However, we are working in a research environment, where unluckily research as opposed to software development takes the majority of the time. We are hard-pressed for time. Some of the programmers are starters, and the ideal situation would be to simplify their lives, before they complicate others'.

Answer (score 1):

The way to deal with such problems is to have *Automatic Builds* and *Tests* running around the clock, triggered by checkins. This is also referred to as *Continuous Integration*. When a build breaks or a test fails, you need to be able to lookup which checkin(s) lead to this and point a finger at the responsible developer(s).

See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870469/is-there-a-tool-for-cross-platform-continuous-integration-c-win32-and-linux) for tools doing this across platforms.

Comment: We have automated builds and finger pointing courtesy Hudson but only run on Windows. Hopefully some day I will find time to implement it also to run using Cygwin/g++. But still compiler errors are much better.

Comment: @Amit: Have a look at [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), then. I have seen it (or helped to) setup from scratch to having something running within a few hours several times. Of the various CI tools I have seen this was by far the easiest to setup, especially across platforms. It should be very easy to setup (virtual) build slave machines using GCC and VC.

Comment: as I said I already use Hudson. The link for cross-platform build tools was useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Amit: I'm sorry I overlooked you saying you're already using hudson. (That's what I get for answering on SO with four kids tugging at my sleeves...) So why don't you just setup a GCC build slave?